# Concatenating columns of lists containing NaNs in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df with two columns having either lists or NaN values. **There are no rows having NaN in both columns**. I want to create a third column that merges the values of the other two columns in the following way:-

```
if row df.a is NaN -> df.c = df.b

if row df.b is Nan -> df.c = df.a

else df.c = df.a + df.b
```

Input:-

```
df
                                 a                                    b
0   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
1   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
2   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
3   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
4   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
5   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
6   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
7   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                  NaN   
8   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]   
9   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]   
10                             NaN  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]   
11                             NaN  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

output:

```
df.c

0   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
5   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
6   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
7   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]                                     
8   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]   
9   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]   
10  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
11  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

I tried to use this nested condition with apply

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.a if x.b is float else (x.b if x.a is float else (x['a'] + x['b'])), axis = 1)
```

but is giving me this error :

> TypeError: ('can only concatenate list (not "float") to list', u'occurred at index 0').

I am using ( and it's acutally working)

```
if x is float
```

because is the only way I found to separate a list from a NaN value.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the `NaN`s to list, and then apply `np.sum`:

```
In [718]: df['c'] = df[['a', 'b']].applymap(lambda x: [] if x != x else x).apply(np.sum, axis=1); df['c']
Out[718]: 
0                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
5                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
6                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
7     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
8     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
9                   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
10                  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
Name: c, dtype: object
```

This works for any number of columns that have list/NaN contents.

Comment: Is there a numpy function that can be used? I have a dataframe with 100 million records and this step takes a lot of time

Answer (score 4):

When you use `pd.DataFrame.stack` null values are dropped by default.  We can then group by the first level of the index and concatenate the lists together with `sum`

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).sum()

0                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
5                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
6                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
7                                        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
8     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
9     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
10                                  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
11                                  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
dtype: object
```

We can then add it to a copy of the dataframe with `assign`

```
df.assign(c=df.stack().groupby(level=0).sum())
```

Or add it to a new column in place

```
df['c'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN`s to `empty list` first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [[0, 1, 2], np.nan, [0, 1, 2]],
                   'b':[np.nan,[0, 1, 2],[ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]})  
print (df)

s = pd.Series([[]], index=df.index)
df['c'] = df['a'].fillna(s) + df['b'].fillna(s)
print (df)
           a                b                         c
0  [0, 1, 2]              NaN                 [0, 1, 2]
1        NaN        [0, 1, 2]                 [0, 1, 2]
2  [0, 1, 2]  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  [0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```